# Can't connect to mysql server on ubuntu 14.04 ERROR 2002 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

When trying to connect I get this message

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I've tried purging mysql-server and reinstalling it, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was attempting to connect over ssh.

I changed the `bind-address` property in `/etc/mysql/my.conf` from `192.168.1.2` to `10.0.0.2`